# Bootstrap popover not displaying near button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use a Bootstrap popover.  It does pop up, but it doesn't appear near my button, and I can't figure out why.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="example1" 
                data-trigger="click" data-container="body" 
                data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" 
                data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
          Popover on top
        </button>
    </div>            
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h3>Client search</h3>
        <div class="input-group col-sm-5">
            <input placeholder="Search for ..." id="search_box" name="search_box"
                   title="Search for ..." class="form-control"  type="text" value="">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#example1').popover();
```

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Comment: Dont know why, but for some reason i have not been able to add screenshots for a while now

Comment: can you please create a http://jsfiddle.net to reproduce this issue ?

Comment: @DhirajBodicherla I have tried to create one but i cant get it worklng as when i click the button nothing happens.  Never used it before

Comment: Here : http://www.bootply.com/sZgfnqKTJZ, I think you have some css making some interference...

Comment: @YenneInfo Thanks but now my popover is at the topleft of the page. I have tried looking at the CSS as nothing is being over-ridden or using any CSS i have created, very peculiar

Comment: Can you share the custom css about your issue ? If you've got time, please take my bootply and modify it with your css in order to reproduce the problem.... else it's not very important, but it's better for the community in order to debug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Popover on top
</button>
```

You can look at the details http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers